# SSRS - Filter multiple times on Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am getting used to report developments under SSRS (2012, moving soon to 2016), but I have one insolvable problem.

To make it quick, my job is to migrate reports from Hyperion Interactive Reporting (know as BRIO) to SSRS. That one functionnality I am in trouble with was existing in BRIO, but I can't manage to do the same with SSRS.

[image: Here is an example of the old filter that I need to reproduce]

The user can choose to filter any fields he wants, with an operator of his choice. He can do that on the number of fields he wants, the selected filters are stored and shown at the right (it's in French btw, sorry for that). Then, he asks for execution and the tables will appear, with all the filters selected.

I was already in trouble making that same kind of filter working only one time, because of the choice of operator (not possible by default in SSRS). My solution was to create 3 parameters, including one with operators, and write all the possible cases in my SQL Stored Procedure.

[image: Here is how my report looks in SSRS for now]

(I have 3 parameters on the left to create that filter, but they only work one time. They can't store a first filter, then a second, etc... and apply all of them when I ask for the report's display)

[image: An idea of my code's structure]

(I did cut the request with [...] to show you the IF with @operator, and the @ColName < @ValueToFilter in the end, it's not a mistake)

This is a very annoying situation, my actual reports are obviously not functionnal but I can't find any idea. Is there a way to do the same with SSRS ? Using multiple times the same parameters, or letting the users filter on the fields they want before of even after execution ? I couldn't find any proper way to do it anywhere on the net.

Thank you by advance for you help or ideas and greetings from Paris,

Robin

> Edit : I'll try to explain it better :

I am developping reports for other collaborators (in a big insurances company). I have to make reports that all of them can use from the web portal, so the reports have to be very flexible.

The team I am working for on this report for instance told me that they can potentially want to apply filters on 15 potential fields. Sometimes only one, sometimes 3, 5, and never the same ones... They need to be able to select the column to filter, to choose the operator, and enter the value to filter. For instance for one execution the year of subscription, >, 2015 ; and the name of the customer, Like, "Bond". Then they ask for the report's display with those filters applied. Which means that I can't define those filters myself before, in the Filter option of my dataset for instance, because it would force me to choose an operator, and I don't want to. The user needs to have that choice.

To say it again in an other way, I have to create a menu in the parameters, that lets the users filter on the fields they want, and I don't know by advance the number of filters to be applied, which fields are going to be filtered, the operator chosen for each field filtered... The problem is there, I have to give a lot of flexibility and choice to the final users of the reports I am developping, but SSRS doesn't seem to be a good solution for that at all...

Comment: That statement looks wide open to injection. `EXEC (N'...WHERE ' + @Variable + N' > ' + @Variable2)` is extremely dangerous. Always properly quote your injected objects and **parametrise** your statements. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Welcome Robin. As far as I know there is no way to do exactly what you want by default. To achieve what you want, you might have to build a custom web front end. Alternatively you could look at Power Bi which integrates with SSRS and build what you want there. Its not ideal for laying out tradition style 'paper' reports as it is an analysis tool but it might be worth looking into if you can't re-think you current report.
 Hopefully other people will have more helpful comments!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments ! I will carefully read and rewrite my code, it was a bit experimental. Thank you for this advice Alan, i will take a look at Power Bi and maybe talk to about it with my collegues if it seems like the best solution. Have a good day !

Comment: Couldn't you just have one query and populate the operator too? `WHERE ' + @COLNAME + ' ' + @OPERATOR + ' ' + @VALUE ` (not that it helps your problem)

Comment: I tried it first, but there is no "operator" type for @operator, so it is not understood as it is supposed to be... But I will try again just to be sure. Thank you !